# ng-Table table content appers when clicking table header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am implementing a little music request web application with AngularJS. The requested titles are shown in a ng-Table that should be able to be sorted.

The .js file looks like this:

```
    var musicApp = angular.module('musicRequests', ['ngResource', 'ngTable']);
    musicApp.controller('MusicRequestsController', ['$scope', 'Music', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', function($scope, Music, $filter, ngTableParams) {
        $scope.musicrequests = Music.query();
        var data = $scope.musicrequests;

        $scope.addRequest = function(newRequest){
            $scope.newMusicRequest = new Music();
            Music.save(newRequest)
            musicrequests.push(newRequest);
        }
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1, 
            count: 10,
            sorting: {
                name: 'asc'
            }
        }, 
        {
            total: data.length,
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
    }]);

    musicApp.factory('Music', ['$resource', function($resource) { 
    return $resource('/musicrequests', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },

    }); 
}]);
```

When the markup looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-stiped" ng-table="tableParams">
    <tr ng-repeat="musicrequest in musicrequests">
        <td data-title="'Artist'" sortable="'artist'">{{ musicrequest.artist }}</td>
        <td data-title="'Title'" sortable="'title'">{{ musicrequest.title }}</td>
        <td data-title="'Guest'" sortable="'guest'">{{ musicrequest.guest }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the table content is rendered but it is not sortable.

when it looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-stiped" ng-table="tableParams">
    <tr ng-repeat="musicrequest in $data">
        <td data-title="'Artist'" sortable="'artist'">{{ musicrequest.artist }}</td>
        <td data-title="'Title'" sortable="'title'">{{ musicrequest.title }}</td>
        <td data-title="'Guest'" sortable="'guest'">{{ musicrequest.guest }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the table content is sortable but when the page is loaded the table is initially blank. When the header is clicked the content appears and can be sorted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that $scope.musicrequests is empty as there may be a pending request to the server.

Try adding:

```
$scope.$watch('musicrequests', function () {
  $scope.tableParams.reload();
});
```

Comment: What if you use var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.musicrequests, params.orderBy()) : $scope.musicrequests; ?

Answer (score 0):

Well i found out, that the param name in the sorting part should be matching to the displayed values (artist, title, guest) and should not be name.